# How can I use FriBidiXeTeX on windows?

Tags: xetex, bidi

The [FriBidiXeTeX](http://ctan.org/pkg/fribidixetex) program is a new package on CTAN which allows using LTR script between RTL script without using any mark-up.

There are instructions on how the program should be compiled on Mac OSX and Linux but how can I compile the program on Windows and use it? Will there be any binaries in MiKTeX or TeXLive for users like me?

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  that's a reasonable question, but the only person likely to know the answer is the author of the package.  that person is actually listed as a user here, but hasn't been seen on the site since february.  the package source is posted on github, and there's a place there to post "issues".  (i think this question qualifies.)

Comment: I tried to build by mingw32 for windows 32bit, but not tested:
`http://www.w32tex.org/toolsw32/fribidixetex.exe`

Comment: @AkiraKakuto: Thanks. If you turn your comment into an answer, I will accept it. I am grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was almost straightforward with mingw by installing

```
fribidi-0.19.7.tar.bz2
```

at

```
https://www.fribidi.org/
```

The result (32bit windows application) can be downloaded from

```
http://www.w32tex.org/toolsw32/fribidixetex.exe
```