# set latin text whitout \lr while xepersian loaded

Tags: fonts, languages, xepersian, persian

I have a problem with my university thesis template, which in in Persian language and loads `xepersian` package with `B Nazanin` Persian font, 
The problem is exactly with `B Nazanin` font. as in template preamble we have:

```
\settextfont{B Nazanin}
\setlatintextfont{Times New Roman}
```

and `B Nazanin` does not support Latin characters. My Latin characters outside an `\lr` environment becomes square like below:

[image]

I wrote 4 chapters of thesis and it's very hard to use `\lr{}` for every single latin part. Is there anyway to correct this problem more easily?

Answer (score 1):

Use the program [`fribidiXeTeX`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fribidixetex). If you are on windows, you can use [the compiled version](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338619) by Akira Kakuto. Otherwise, compile from source yourself.

If `test.tex` contains

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas}
\setdigitfont{Yas}
\let\fribidixetexLRE\lr
\let\fribidixetexRLE\rl
\let\fribidixetexlatinnumbers\lr
\let\fribidixetexnonlatinnumbers\rl
%BIDION
\begin{document}    
این یک پاراگراف «پارسی» است به نام Simple text و این یک عدد 0887 به لاتین است.
%BIDIOFF
\begin{equation}
1+2=3\label{eq:1}
\end{equation}
%BIDION
این فرمول شماره
\ref{eq:1}
است.
%BIDILTR
\begin{latin}
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
\end{latin}
%BIDION
و ادامه متن که بعد از متن Lorem Imsum قرار می‌گیرد.
\end{document}
%BIDIOFF
```

By running

```
fribidixetex -n test.tex -o test.ltx
```

You get the file `test.ltx` in which all your latin short texts are automatically placed inside `\lr`. You will then need to run

```
xelatex test.ltx
```

to produce the pdf output.